# Recursive SQL: aggregate function using Recursive Subquery Factoring

Tags: sql, recursion, hierarchy, recursive-query, oracle11gr2

Table T represents a tree. Every record is a node and each node has only one parent.

This query calculates the SUM() of each branch for every node.

```
WITH t AS
        (SELECT  1 id, NULL parent_id, NULL value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 10 id,    1 parent_id, 1000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 20 id,    1 parent_id, 2000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 30 id,   10 parent_id, 3000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 40 id,   10 parent_id, 4000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 50 id,   20 parent_id, 5000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 60 id,    1 parent_id, 6000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 70 id,   60 parent_id, 7000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 80 id,   70 parent_id, 8000 value FROM dual
    ) SELECT CAST(LPAD(' ', (LEVEL-1)*4) || ID AS VARCHAR2(20))  id
        ,VALUE                                                   self_value
        ,(SELECT SUM (value)
          FROM   t t2
          CONNECT BY 
            PRIOR t2.ID = t2.parent_id
            START WITH t2.id = t.id)                             branch_value
      FROM   t
      CONNECT BY PRIOR t.id = t.parent_id
      START WITH t.parent_id IS NULL
      ORDER SIBLINGS BY t.id;
```

```
ID                   SELF_VALUE BRANCH_VALUE
-------------------- ---------- ------------
1                                      36000
    10                     1000         8000
        30                 3000         3000
        40                 4000         4000
    20                     2000         7000
        50                 5000         5000
    60                     6000        21000
        70                 7000        15000
            80             8000         8000

9 rows selected.
```

I've been trying to achieve the same result of this query using the alternative Subquery Factoring syntax. Any help would be truly appreciated !

Comment: As you said ´and each node has only one parent´ is your format wrong on the question? 30 and 40 has 10 as parent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jorge.. what I mean is that every node/record has only one parent. In a tree structure, each parent may have several  children. That's what happen with #30 and #40, both having #10 as their parent. Let me know if this is not clear enough.

Comment: Own... thanks. English is not my primary language and I always mix parent with child. Sorry. And I have a question, you want to do this without the WITH command is that it?

Comment: No Jorge,.. take a look at [Recursive Subquery Factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) doc from Oracle and see some examples at the end of the article to see what it is. I want to do this without the CONNECT BY clause

Comment: Here's what I've got so far; sadly not quite there yet / I'm not familiar enough with Oracle...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32449

Comment: Thank you @JohnLBevan, but you're not allowed to use neither DISTINCT nor GROUP BY into the recursive member of a subquery factoring. On the other side, keep in mind that hierarchy is not limited to two levels, it could be indefinite deep (theorethically)

Answer (score 0):

Until `GROUP BY` is supported in recursive queries, I think it's not possible with only one query. So I added a second subquery in the `WITH`-clause. Maybe this is sufficient for your problem (nice brain-teasers).

This will calculate the data:

```
WITH t AS
        (SELECT  1 id, NULL parent_id, NULL value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 10 id,    1 parent_id, 1000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 20 id,    1 parent_id, 2000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 30 id,   10 parent_id, 3000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 40 id,   10 parent_id, 4000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 50 id,   20 parent_id, 5000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 60 id,    1 parent_id, 6000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 70 id,   60 parent_id, 7000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 80 id,   70 parent_id, 8000 value FROM dual),
hierarchy (id,ancestor,value) AS (
  SELECT t.id,t.id,t.value
    FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id,h.ancestor,t.value
    FROM t
      INNER JOIN hierarchy h
        ON t.parent_id = h.id)
SELECT h.ancestor, t.parent_id, t.value, SUM(h.value)
  FROM hierarchy h
    INNER JOIN t
      ON t.id = h.ancestor
  GROUP BY h.ancestor,t.value,t.parent_id;
```

To get the same order and formatting as described in the question add calculation of path and depth:

```
WITH t AS
        (SELECT  1 id, NULL parent_id, NULL value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 10 id,    1 parent_id, 1000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 20 id,    1 parent_id, 2000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 30 id,   10 parent_id, 3000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 40 id,   10 parent_id, 4000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 50 id,   20 parent_id, 5000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 60 id,    1 parent_id, 6000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 70 id,   60 parent_id, 7000 value FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 80 id,   70 parent_id, 8000 value FROM dual),
hierarchy (id,ancestor,value,depth,path) AS (
  SELECT t.id,t.id,t.value,0,''||t.id
    FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id,h.ancestor,t.value,h.depth+1,h.path||'.'||t.id
    FROM t
      INNER JOIN hierarchy h
        ON t.parent_id = h.id)
SELECT LPAD(h.ancestor,p.depth*4+1,' ') AS id, t.value AS self_value, SUM(h.value) as branch_value
  FROM hierarchy h
    INNER JOIN t
      ON t.id = h.ancestor
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id,depth,path
                  FROM hierarchy
                  WHERE ancestor IN (SELECT id FROM t WHERE parent_id IS NULL)
                  ORDER BY path) p
      ON p.id = t.id
  GROUP BY h.ancestor,t.value,t.parent_id,p.path,p.depth
  ORDER BY p.path;
```

Comment: Hi user, nice job!.. Totals are OK but I'm trying to rewrite your version in order to achieve the same output of the original version (DEPTH FIRST) which is the other goal of the problem.

Comment: I added a second query, that additionally calculates the path and the depth to order and format the output in the exact same manner as described in the question.